# How small can a spherical clear glass bead be before it loses it's transparency?

Tags: optics

I don't know if it'll help but I'm trying to use these as tracker particles in water.
Edit: I mean it'll start scattering light. I know glass beads of size about 30 micron and less appear white under a regular light.
Edit 2: I know the scattering would also depend on the wavelength of light falling on it. But as I mentioned above, what would be range of size around which the beads appear to loss their transparency.

Comment: Strictly speaking the transparency is not a function of size (in fact smaller is better) but there are other surface phenomena (scatter) that tend to become dominant  when you have many small particles. What exactly are you trying to do/ask? More context will give a better answer.

Comment: Why do you assume that it will lose its transparency? It will scatter differently than a large bead, but it won't become absorptive because of its size. What are you trying to track?

Comment: Any amount of glass, even one molecule, would still be transparent in optical frequencies.

Comment: If you illuminate them with blue light, they will appear blue, in red light they will be red. With white light you should be seeing halos under the right conditions.

Comment: @CuriousOne I'm trying to do some flow visualization. If you look at very small beads, like I said that 30 micron small beads, appear white (as if opaque)

Comment: How can you be sure about glass clarity if the beads appear opaque? Maybe they are made out of some lower quality milky glass? Also, surface quality: for smaller bead diameter the _relative_ surface roughness will be larger (even assuming the same absolute roughness), so more light will be scattered. And last, many beads together will look white due to multiple reflections, same as snow looks white, whereas a single snowflake is transparent. If you put some beads on a black surface, do they still appear opaque white?

Comment: @gigacyan Okay so if you put many beads together is there a critical diameter to distance ratio which gives "opacity". Because this is precisely my problem. I can be sure of the clarity of the bead because a single bead under a microscope seemed transparent

Comment: @Nickbk201 If you put many beads together, you should look at the total number of surface interfaces the light has to travel across. With 20 surfaces (10 beads) more than half of the light will be scattered (more precisely: reflected in random directions).